# How can one use activemq not locally?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I can't understand how to use ActiveMQ not locally.
Suppose I have 2 machines, which need to exchange some messages.
On the on machine I start ActiveMQ broker:

```
> ~/bin/activemq
```

and use something like:

```
    javax.naming.Context ctx = new InitialContext();

    TopicConnectionFactory factory = (TopicConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("connectionFactory");
    conn = factory.createTopicConnection();

    TopicSession session = conn.createTopicSession(false,TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Topic topic = null;
    try{
        topic = (Topic)ctx.lookup("MyTopic");
        System.out.println("MyTopic was found");
    }catch(NameNotFoundException nnfe){
        topic = session.createTopic("MyTopic");
        System.out.println("MyTopic was created");
    }
    TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage();
    TopicPublisher publisher = session.createPublisher(topic);
    conn.start();

    textMessage.setText("My topic message number");
    publisher.publish(textMessage);
    System.out.println("sendMessage2topic");
```

where in jndi.properties I have:

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = tcp://localhost:61616
```

But what should I create on the other machine to subscribe on this topic? Shoul I create second local ActiveMQ broker ont the 2-nd machine, and how to subscribe on the remote topic that is on the first machine???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line...

```
java.naming.provider.url = tcp://localhost:61616
```

...tells your `connectionFactory` to connect with the loopback interface. You can specify here  address of the **remote** broker.

In such case your snippet will send message to the remote broker. Now it is up to broker to distribute the message over the registered subscribers (both local and remote ones).

In this scenario *no broker is created* (neither locally or remotely). You just connect to the existing broker. Of course, you can also create a local broker and configure it to route messages to the remote one (for example, you can do it via static/dynamic network transport or peer network transport protocol). ActiveMQ provides you *a lot* of integration topologies and patterns - but at first you must define what actually you want to achieve.

Comment: Isn't that the URL that does the JNDI connection though?  Wouldn't the URL to connect to the broker be embedded in the ConnectionFactory object?

Answer (score 7):

localhost:61616 will make activeMQ listen on loopback(127.0.0.1) interface only. Use the IP of the machine or 0.0.0.0 instead.

Comment: ok, on the on machine I will use the IP of first machine, BUT problem is same as before: on the second machine what should I use?

Comment: @rauch: What I meant is that in ActiveMQ **Broker** configuration file, in transportConnector element use tcp. URI attribute of transportConnector should use IP instead of localhost

Comment: Nice one!! Completely forgot about "0.0.0.0". This way you can use localhost on the server and you can connect externally with the IP of the server too!

Comment: Thank you sooo much. 0.0.0.0 worked for me. This was a better solution then adding the system IP

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like below. substitute the ipaddress with the target ip you want to use

```
java.naming.provider.url = tcp://172.16.202.168:61616
```